# I have this error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

This is my code I am not sure why it isnt allowing me to upload new files to my site.

```
   const multer = require("multer");

   const upload = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() });

    router.post(
      "/admin/products/new",
      requireAuth,
      [requireTitle, requirePrice],
      upload.single("image"),
      handleErrors(productsNewTemplate),
      async (req, res) => {
        const image = req.file.buffer.toString("base64");
        const { title, price } = req.body;
        await productsRepo.create({ title, price, image });

        res.redirect("/admin/products");
      }
    );

    //I have only posted the snippets i need help with,
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your front end code has the correct name attribute.

```
<input type="file" name="image" />
```

Comment: yeah its looking good...
            <div class="field">
              <label class="label">Image</label>            
              <input type="file" name="image" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <button class="button is-primary">Create</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    `